# Java: Class -Xmx1g not found

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, plesk, youtrack

I am trying to run a Program called "YouTrack" on my server. It did always work, but after the server restarted i am getting an error message when i want to start YouTrack.

Class -Xmx1g could not be found.

I am executing this command:

`java –Xmx1g –XX:MaxPermSize=500m –Djava.awt.headless=true –jar youtrack-6.5.16932.jar 8112`

My system:

- ubuntu 14.04
- Plesk
- java version "1.7.0_79"

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Updated to java version "1.8.0_77". Still doesn't work.

Comment: Other things I would suspect. 1. it isn't invoking the Java you think. 2. There is a localization/character set issue (e.g., the "-" isn't a dash).

Comment: @KevinO That was the Problem. I unknowingly copied the en dash from office. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did Java 7 allow the "g" modifier on the size? I thought that came with Java 8.

- Java 7

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html

-Xmxn
Specifies the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2 MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.

- Java 8

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

-Xmxsize
Specifies the maximum size (in bytes) of the memory allocation pool in bytes. This value must be a multiple of 1024 and greater than 2 MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to indicate megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration. For server deployments, -Xms and -Xmx are often set to the same value. See the section "Ergonomics" in Java SE HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html.

Comment: java –Xmx1024m ......  also doesn't work

Comment: For an experiment, what happens when you remove the parameter?

Comment: Then the –XX:MaxPermSize=500m throws the error. Even if i remove every option, it throws Class youtrack-6.5.16932.jar not found.

Comment: What does `which java` indicate? And are you trying this from a shell, or from within a script of some type?